# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process with random long run mean

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I am considering an OU process of the form
$$ dx_t = \theta(\mu-x_t)dt + \sigma dW_t $$
where $\kappa, \sigma>0$ and $W_t$ is a Brownian motion. I know that $x_t$ has expectation given by:
$$ \mathbb{E}[x_t]=x_0 e^{-\theta t}+(1−e^{-\theta t})\ . $$
I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56412/analytic-solution-to-a-generalized-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process) what happens when $\mu$ is a function of time but I was wondering what happens when $\mu$ is a stochastic process. For instance, what happens when $\mu$ satisfies the SDE:
$$d\mu_t = \gamma dt + \beta dB_t\ ,$$
where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion?

Comment: Assuming $B$ is independent of $W$, we can just condition on $\mu_t$, $$\mathbb{E}\left[x_t \left | \mu_t \right. \right] = x_0 e^{-\theta t} + \mu_t \left(1 - e^{-\theta t}\right).$$ Then taking the expectation again, we get by the tower property that $$\mathbb{E}\left[x_t\right] = x_0 e^{-\theta t} + \mathbb{E}\left[\mu_t\right]\left(1- e^{-\theta t}\right) = x_0 e^{-\theta t} + \gamma t\left(1- e^{-\theta t}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you @Shiva

Comment: @Shiva It seems a little surprising that just knowing the value of $\mu_t$ is enough to compute $\mathbb{E}[x_t]$.  Shouldn't the whole path $(\mu_s)_{s \le t}$ play a role?

Comment: @user6247850 I guess this is the case because $\mu$ is a martingale

Comment: $\mu$ isn't a martingale, though - it has a drift.  I think we can still get a fairly nice expression for $\mathbb{E}[x_t]$, but it's not the one in @Shiva's comment.

Comment: @user6247850 Yes you're right. I was originally thinking that it would be okay since $\mu$ is a Markov process but on further reflection, $x$ is indeed a function for the entire path, so directly plugging $mu_t$ into the formula is not valid as I originally thought. Apologies Zwei, please disregard my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the standard strategy for explicitly solving the SDE of an OU process we can solve
$$ dx_t = \theta \left(\mu_t - x_t\right)dt + \sigma dW_t \quad\quad \mu_t = \gamma t + \beta B_t,$$
with $W$ and $B$ independent Brownian motions. As user6247850 suggested, this then gives a nice expression for $\mathbb{E}\left[x_t\right]$. We have
$$d\left(e^{\theta t} x_t\right) = \theta e^{\theta t}x_t dt + e^{\theta t}\left(\theta \left(\mu_t - x_t\right)dt + \sigma dW_t\right) = e^{\theta t} \left(\theta \mu_t dt + \sigma dW_t\right). $$
Then this means that we get
$$ e^{\theta t} x_t = x_0 + \theta\int_0^te^{\theta s} \left(\gamma s + \beta B_s\right) ds + \int_0^t e^{\theta s}dW_s. $$
Bring rearranging and using integration by parts,
$$x_t = e^{-\theta t}\left(x_0 + \frac{\gamma}{\theta}\right) + \gamma t - \frac{\gamma}{\theta} + \beta B_t - \beta \int_0^t e^{-\theta\left(t-s\right)}dB_s + \sigma \int_0^t e^{-\theta(t-s)}dW_s.$$
The last three terms being a martingale starting at zero, the expectation is given by
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[x_t\right] = e^{-\theta t}\left(x_0 + \frac{\gamma}{\theta}\right) + \gamma t - \frac{\gamma}{\theta}.$$